# Initializing an array so that each element of it would be equal to its index

Tags: scala

I want to initialize an array so that each element of it would be equal to its index:

```
def method1(obj: AnyRef) = {
  //.... 
  if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Int]]) {
      val arr1 = obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]
      val arr2: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](arr1.length)
      // initialize arr2. How?
      arr2 // arr2[0] = 0, arr2[1] = 1, etc....
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert `Range` to `Array`.

```
var arr2 = (0 until arr1.length).toArray
```

Method `indices` on collection returns `Range`:

```
var arr2 = arr1.indices.toArray
```

If you have an array and want to fill it you could use `copyToArray` method:

```
(0 until arr2.length).copyToArray(arr2)
```

There is no performance difference between this methods: `toArray` is [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L249) by the method `copyToArray`.

`Range` contains only 3 `Int` fields: `start`, `end` and `step`, so there is almost no memory overhead.

There is also method `range` in the [`Array`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array%24) object:

```
val arr2 = Array.range(0, arr1.length) // contains 0, excludes arr1.length
```

There are also some other methods to fill array. These methods are not so useful in this case.

Method `fill`:

```
var i = -1
val arr2 = Array.fill(arr1.length)({i+=1; i})
```

Method `apply`:

```
val arr2 = Array.apply(0, (1 until arr1.length): _*) // Array(0) on empty arr1
```

In case you have not `Array` collection and you want to change its elements and get `Array` you could use `collection.breakOut` method:

```
// this is not that case
val arr2: Array[Int] = (0 until arr1.length).map(identity)(breakOut)
```

Comment: it should be "until" instead of "to", shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

For index based initializations we have the `tabulate` methods. In your case:

```
val arr2 = Array.tabulate(arr1.length)(index => index)
```

or, shorter

```
val arr2 = Array.tabulate(arr1.length)(identity)
```